# Factorisation of numbers sum with exponent $12$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $n^{12}+64$ has at least four distinct factors other than $1$ and itself?

I applied $a^3+b^3$ identity.

Comment: What is $n$, positive integer or real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the familiar factorization of $a^3+b^3$, we get the factors $n^4+4$ and $n^8-4n^4+16$. Now note the perhaps a little surprising factorization $$n^4+4=(n^2-2n+2)(n^2+2n+2).$$
 If $n\gt 1$, then $n^2-2n+2$, $n^2+2n+2$, $(n^2-2n+2)(n^8-4n^4+16)$ and $(n^2+2n+2)(n^8-4n^4+16)$ are obviously distinct non-trivial factors. There are others.

Comment: @JChau Every polynomial over the reals numbers splits into linear or quadratic factors. But for the question the factorisation has to be over the integers. Here you can factorise over the complex numbers by identifying the $12^{th}$ roots of $-64$, and you get a real factorisation by pairing complex conjugate roots.

Comment: For "more than enough factors", one should be careful about  $\gcd(n^4+4,n^8-4n^4+16)$. Indeed $n^8-4n^4+16=(n^4+4)(n^4-8)+48$ shows $\gcd(n^4+4,n^8-4n^4+16)\mid 48$. Also, $3\not\mid n^4+4$, hence $\gcd(n^4+4,n^8-4n^4+16)\mid16$. If $n$ is even, then $2^6\mid n^{12}+64$ and all is fine (we have divisors $2,4,8,16$). If $n$ is odd, we conclude $\gcd(n^4+4,n^8-4n^4+16)=1$. Pick primes $p,q$ with $p\mid n^ 4+4$, $q\mid n^8-4n^4+16$. Then $N=pqr$ with $r>1$ (because $n^4+4>p$) and we have at least the divisors $p,q,pq,pr$ if $r\ne q$ and the divisors $p,q,pq,q^2$ if $r=q$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I think little detail is needed. For $n=2$ we automatically get lots, and if $n\ge 3$ then a glance at the sizes does it.

Comment: How to arrive at the factorisation of n^4+4=(n^2-2*n+2)(n^2+2*n+2)

Comment: The factorization is easy to ^verify*. How would one come to it? Maybe by seeing that $n^4+4$ is a difference of squares, $(n^2+2)^2-(2n)^2$, which factors in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

The given statement is false. At $n=1$,

$$1+64=65=5\times 13$$

Answer (score 1):

We have to factor $n^{12}+64$. I will show you how to do this
$$n^{12}+64$$
$$=n^{12}+2^6$$
$$=\left(n^4\right)^3+\left(2^2\right)^3$$
Rule: $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$
$$\left(n^4+2^2\right)\left(\left(n^4\right)^2-n^4\cdot 2^2+\left(2^2\right)^2\right)$$
$$=\left(n^4+4\right)\left(n^8-4n^4+16\right)$$
You cannot simplify this any further. There are only two factors. If you must find four factors, you can use the sum of squares, i.e. $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$, where $i$ denotes the imaginary unit, to factor $n^4+4$
$$\left(n^2+2i\right)\left(n^2-2i\right)\left(n^8-4n^4+16\right)$$
For $n^8-4n^4+16$, let $n^4=x$.

$$n^8-4n^4+16=x^2-4x+16$$
Using quadratic formula:
$$x=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{(-4)^2-4(1)(16)}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-64}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{-48}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{4\pm 4\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
$$x=2\pm 2\sqrt{-3}$$
$$n^4=2\pm 2i\sqrt{3}$$
The remaining two factors are: $n^4-2-2i\sqrt{3}$ and $n^4-2+2i\sqrt{3}$
$$\color{green}{n^{12}+64=\left(n^2+2i\right)\left(n^2-2i\right)\left(n^4-2-2i\sqrt{3}\right)\left(n^4-2+2i\sqrt{3}\right)}$$

Comment: See Andre's answer for factorization of $n^4+4$.